# error 'using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK \IBM was unexpected at this time.' when trying to start logstash on my pc

Tags: java, logstash, java-11

I'm trying to start logstash on my machine, but got below error

```
C:\Users\xxx\Tool\logstash-7.13.3\bin>logstash -f ../test_cyrark_proxy.conf
"test"
Using JAVA_HOME defined java:  "C:\Users\xxx\Tool\logstash-7.13.3\jdk\bin\java.exe"
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
\IBM was unexpected at this time.
```

I checked my JAVA setup.

My `JAVA_HOME` value is:

```
C:\Users\xxx>ECHO %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Software\319576_JDK_11.0_19w64`
```

JAVA Version is:

```
C:\Users\xxx>java --version
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)`
```

I tried to run with DEBUG mode too, but output is the same.

```
logstash -f ../test_cyberark_proxy.conf --log.level DEBUG
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: That looks like a "warning", not an error. If you don't like it, do `set JAVA_HOME=;logstash -f ../test_cyrark_proxy.conf "test"`

Comment: @g00se The index is not created though. How can I see more detailed logs?

Comment: That would be a different error. I don't know offhand but it's not what you asked your question about

Comment: The message "was unexpected at this time" is the sort of error reported by `cmd.exe` if it encounters an error parsing a batch script. Spaces in file paths are notorious for causing these kinds of problems. Does the username you have obscured using `xxx` contain a space, by any chance?

Comment: @LukeWoodward xxx was just added to replace my username. No space there. The solution provided by g00se did suppress the error. It's just that I still don't know why the data was not synced to logstash.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I've not used Logstash before. I only commented to say that the 'was unrecognised at this time' message was likely something generated by `cmd.exe`.